Does the C standard provide a definition for term "array of unknown size"?
Does the C standard provide a definition for term "array of unknown size" [1]?
Despite that the term "array of unknown size" is perhaps obvious to understand (e.g. an array for which the size is not known), is it defined by the C standard?
Searching the C11 for "unknown size" and for "incomplete type" (it is relevant) produces, in particular, the following results:

If the size is not present, the array type is an incomplete type.


An array type of unknown size is an incomplete type.

Here we see "if A, then B" and "C is B". From that we cannot (?) deduce that "if A, then C".
[1] Not to be confused with "a variable length array type of unspecified size" (i.e. the term "unspecified size" is reserved for VLA). The C11, however, describes extern int y[]; as "array of int of unspecified size", which is an oversight. It was fixed in C2X (n3299.pdf): "array of int of unknown size".

Well, it seems by the references you found that the term for an array of unknown size is indeed "array of unknown size" ;-). Particularly convincing is the editorial change in n3299 you mention.

C has also flexible array members which are arrays of unknown size :)

C23 (ISO/IEC 9899:2024) has been published, so we do not have to refer to it as C2X anymore. Unless you tag the question with a particular version of the standard, I assume the question is about the current version (C23).

My take is that both arrays with no size specified as well as arrays where the size is not yet available (external linkage etc), then the array is incomplete. See C23 6.2.5 §1, the definition of the term incomplete. "At various points within a translation unit an object type may be incomplete  (lacking sufficient information to determine the
size of objects of that type)"

@nielsen I have no access to the published C23 (ISO/IEC 9899:2024). I have access to (C2X) working drafts. I'm not sure that many people here do have access to the published C23.

Even if the size of given, it may be unknown and unchecked by the compiler. A function argument may specify a size such as void fun(int arr[4]) but the size isn't actually considered. It is perfectly legal to pass int a[3] or int b[5], since they all decay to pointers.
